# How to solve "make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/generic/root/file_contexts', needed by `snod'. Stop."

Tags: android, qmake

I am building the source code of android these days, and I encountered a problem and find It is hard to solve for me, the problem is :

When I first build the whole source code ,I can get the right result, the `system.img`, `userdata.img`, `ramdisk.img` .. all the final `.img` exist, and then I try to do some modification to the apps in the folder `/packages/app/`, when I execute the command `make snod` and there comes an error :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/generic/root/file_contexts', needed by `snod'.  Stop.
```

The entire steps I excute is :

```
   # source build/envsetup.sh
   # lunch full-eng
   # mmm /package/apps/Calculator( just take Calculator for example)
   # make snod
```

but this time, I can't see and `.img` files in the folder `/out/target/product/generic`, I have no idea, Could anyone help me?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

```
#
```

Hello, I also encountered this problem when I tried 'make snod' to add an app to the system image. It occured to me that maybe the build settings are incorrect so that 'make snod' failed. Here's my try(change your pwd to the Android Open Source Project root directory first):

```
$ source ./build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch 6
$ mmm ./packages/experimental/HelloAndroid/
$ make snod
```

I run 'make' by choosing the 'lunch 6' combo, so I refreshed the settings by doing that again. After that, it success. Hope this could help you.